# Writing sqlplus output to a file

Tags: oracle

Using sqlplus.exe I'm looking for a way to write sqlplus output to a file.

Is there anyway I can do that, currently the output is written only to the console.

Comment: The `SPOOL` command given in the answers is described [in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_six.htm#i1082570).

Answer (score 81):

You may use the SPOOL command to write the information to a file.

Before executing any command type the following:

```
SPOOL <output file path>
```

All commands output following will be written to the output file.

To stop command output writing type

```
SPOOL OFF
```

Answer (score 41):

Also note that the `SPOOL` output is driven by a few SQLPlus settings:

- `SET LINESIZE nn` - maximum line width; if the output is longer it will wrap to display the contents of each result row.
- `SET TRIMSPOOL OFF|ON` - if set `OFF` (the default), every output line will be padded to `LINESIZE`. If set `ON`, every output line will be trimmed.
- `SET PAGESIZE nn` - number of lines to output for each repetition of the header. If set to zero, no header is output; just the detail.

Those are the biggies, but there are some others to consider if you just want the output without all the SQLPlus chatter.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have the access to the directory you are trying to spool. I tried to spool to root and it did not created the file (e.g `c:\test.txt`). You can check where you are spooling by issuing `spool` command.

Comment: The last pointer just echoes what was set using the spool command. It doesn't give the full absolute path which is what I want.

Comment: does this work with linux also ? i tried by giving /tmp location in my linuxbox. But i got errors : 'Encountered the symbol "SPOOL" '. Is there any workaround for this ?

Answer (score 3):

just to save my own deductions from all this is (for saving DBMS_OUTPUT output on the client, using sqlplus):

- no matter if i use Toad/with polling or sqlplus, for a long running script with occasional dbms_output.put_line commands, i will get the output in the end of the script execution
- set serveroutput on; and dbms_output.enable(); should be present in the script
- to save the output SPOOL command was not enough to get the DBMS_OUTPUT lines printed to a file - had to use the usual `>` windows CMD redirection. the passwords etc. can be given to the empty prompt, after invoking sqlplus. also the "/" directives and the "exit;" command should be put either inside the script, or given interactively as the password above (unless it is specified during the invocation of sqlplus)

Answer (score 1):

In windows type this command:

```
sqlplus.exe username/password@servicename @yourquery.sql > out.txt
```

besides, you should write an `exit` command at the end of "yourquery.sql" file.